# Python inserting characters in strings next to a specefic letters

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a problem with adding `p` + **vowel** after a given **vowel** in a `string` using Python.

For example:

If I write `welcome`, the program would print `wepelcopomepe`.

Comment: Could you please give a snippet of your code which is not working. Stack overflow is for fixing and improving problems, not creating new pieces of code!

Comment: Why are people downvoting the question? It is quite clear...

Comment: @BrunoLubascher  : read [ask] - first thing to do is `research` - second thing to do is `good title` next thing is post your `code` etc. See how many things this post did - if they are lacking it will get downvotes. SO is not for "Here is my task - gimme code" - it is about getting helped after spending considerable amount of work on the problem and getting stuck.

Comment: @PatrickArtner funny how in the link is written **To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips** and not **Here are excuses for you to downvote a question**. I read the question and immediately knew what they guy wanted, why not use the site to help people?

Comment: @BrunoLubascher  because we collect and build a Q&A for future readers - for that good quality questions are more important then helping one guy/gal. Hover over the downvote arrow to see its hint-text - posting a _Task_ here without any effort to solve it may be considered to "show no research effort".

Comment: @PatrickArtner I see your point... I just don't know how we can ever expect these new users to learn to write good questions if we downvote them so quickly that they can never even edit their question...

Comment: @PatrickArtner The thing is that i had no idea how to even start on solving the problem. I was searching on google, but i couldn't find anything anywhere, that's why there is nothing written there. I am happy that people accually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **regex**. Here is an example:

```
import re

s = 'welcome'

new_s = re.sub('([aeiou])', '\g<1>p\g<1>', s)

print(new_s)
> wepelcopomepe
```

Comment: No problem ;)
Btw, next time you write a question, try to make it more clear and nicely formatted, so people don't start downvoting so quickly...

Comment: your solution is sound though :)